# passing arg 1 of `strcspn' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, newline, c-strings

so i'm making a function that gets 10 names. I tried to use strcspn() to remove the \n from the end of the string. However I get this warning.

```
#define NUM_OF_NAMES 10
#define STR_LEN 50

void input (char arr[][STR_LEN]);


int main()
{
    char str [NUM_OF_NAMES][STR_LEN] = {0};
    input(str);

    return 0;
}
void input (char arr[][STR_LEN])
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter 10 names:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_NAMES; i++)
    {
        fgets(arr[i], STR_LEN, stdin);
        arr[i][strcspn(arr, "\n")] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_NAMES; i++)
    {
        puts(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first parameter should be `char *` and not array of pointers (or `char []` and not `char [][]` to match your declarations).

Comment: Tip: Better code would test the result of `fgets()` before using `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have entered  a string

```
    fgets(arr[i], STR_LEN, stdin);
```

and are going to remove the appended new line character of the string. Then use the string!

```
    arr[i][strcspn(arr[i], "\n")] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `arr` to `strcspn()`: the type is incorrect as `arr` is a pointer to an array of arrays of `STR_LEN` characters.  You should pass `arr[i]` instead, which decays to a pointer to an array of `char`, which is the expected type for the both arguments of `strcspn()`.

Note that you should also test the return value of `fgets()` to detect unexpected end of file and avoid unexpected behavior.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_OF_NAMES 10
#define STR_LEN 50

int input(char arr[][STR_LEN]);

int main() {
    char str[NUM_OF_NAMES][STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    input(str);

    return 0;
}

int input(char arr[][STR_LEN]) {
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter 10 names:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_NAMES; i++) {
        if (!fgets(arr[i], STR_LEN, stdin))
            break;
        arr[i][strcspn(arr[i], "\n")] = '\0';
    }
    n = i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        puts(arr[i]);
    }
    return n;
}
```